# Python - Find matching string(s) between DataFrame column (scraped text) and list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I am having an hard time comparing the strings from a DataFrame column with a list of strings.

Let me explain to you:
I collected data from social media for a personal project, and aside of that I created a list of string like the following:

```
the_list = ['AI', 'NLP', 'approach', 'AR Cloud', 'Army_Intelligence', 'Artificial general intelligence', 'Artificial tissue', 'artificial_insemination', 'artificial_intelligence', 'augmented intelligence', 'augmented reality', 'authentification', 'automaton', 'Autonomous driving', 'Autonomous vehicles', 'bidirectional brain-machine interfaces', 'Biodegradable', 'biodegradable', 'Biotech', 'biotech', 'biotechnology', 'BMI', 'BMIs', 'body_mass_index', 'bourdon', 'Bradypus_tridactylus', 'cognitive computing', 'commercial UAVs', 'Composite AI', 'connected home', 'conversational systems', 'conversational user interfaces', 'dawdler', 'Decentralized web', 'Deep fakes', 'Deep learning', 'defrayal']
```

There are other words but this is just to give you an idea.

My goal is to compare EACH of this list's words, with 2 existing DF columns which contains titles and posts messages (from reddit). To be clear, I want to create a new column where to display the words which match between my list to the columns containing the posts.

So far, this is what I have done:

```
the_list = ['AI', 'NLP', 'approach', 'AR Cloud', 'Army_Intelligence', 'Artificial general intelligence', 'Artificial tissue', 'artificial_insemination', 'artificial_intelligence', 'augmented intelligence', 'augmented reality', 'authentification', 'automaton', 'Autonomous driving', 'Autonomous vehicles', 'bidirectional brain-machine interfaces', 'Biodegradable', 'biodegradable', 'Biotech', 'biotech', 'biotechnology', 'BMI', 'BMIs', 'body_mass_index', 'bourdon', 'Bradypus_tridactylus', 'cognitive computing', 'commercial UAVs', 'Composite AI', 'connected home', 'conversational systems', 'conversational user interfaces', 'dawdler', 'Decentralized web', 'Deep fakes', 'Deep learning', 'defrayal']

df['matched text'] = df.text_lemmatized.str.extract('({0})'.format('|'.join(the_list)), flags = re.IGNORECASE)
df = df[~pd.isna(df['matched text'])]

df

>>Outpout:

      title_lemmatized   text_lemmatized        matched_word(s)
0         Title1       'claim thorough vet...'      'ai'
1         Title@       'Yeaaah today iota...'       'IoT'
```

[Here the output result for more details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdlF7.png)

**The issue:** The main problem is that its returning me letters (not actual words) that matches the list.

Example:

--> the_list = 'ai' (for artificial intelligence) or IoT (for Internet of Things)

--> df['text_lemmatized'] has the word 'claim' in the text, then 'ai' will be the match. or 'Iota' will match with 'IoT'.

**What I wish:**

```
   title_lemmatized       text_lemmatized             matched_word(s)
0    Title1         'AI claim that Iot devises...'      'AI', 'IoT'
1    Title2         'The claim story about...'
2    Title3         'augmented reality and ai are...'   'augmented reality', 'ai'
3    Title4         'AI ai or artificial intelligence'  'AI', 'ai', 'artificial intelligence'
```

Thanks lot :)

Comment: You have to use [regex word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`. Try something like `r'\b({0})\b'.format('|'.join(the_list))`.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I figured where it was coming from. Simply from the '|' instead of '  |  '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add word boundaries `'\b'` to your regex pattern. From the [re module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> `\b`
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string. This means that r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.

Besides that, you want to use [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) (or `Series.str.extractall`) instead of `Series.str.extract` to find all the matches.

This should work

```
the_list = ['AI', 'NLP', 'approach', 'AR Cloud', 'Army_Intelligence', 'Artificial general intelligence', 'Artificial tissue', 'artificial_insemination', 'artificial_intelligence', 'augmented intelligence', 'augmented reality', 'authentification', 'automaton', 'Autonomous driving', 'Autonomous vehicles', 'bidirectional brain-machine interfaces', 'Biodegradable', 'biodegradable', 'Biotech', 'biotech', 'biotechnology', 'BMI', 'BMIs', 'body_mass_index', 'bourdon', 'Bradypus_tridactylus', 'cognitive computing', 'commercial UAVs', 'Composite AI', 'connected home', 'conversational systems', 'conversational user interfaces', 'dawdler', 'Decentralized web', 'Deep fakes', 'Deep learning', 'defrayal']

pat = r'\b({0})\b'.format('|'.join(the_list))
df['matched text'] = df.text_lemmatized.str.findall(pat, flags = re.IGNORECASE).map(", ".join)
```